# What does ngStorage's $sync() do?

Tags: angularjs, ng-storage

ngStorage is a wrapper for the browser's localStorage and sessionStorage objects for AngularJS.

Besides re-exposing the get/set methods, it also provides a $sync() method.  But localStorage and sessionStorage reads & writes are already synchronous, so what does the $sync method do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular service accepts objects but browser storage only accepts strings. So it basically uses a proxy object with gettor/settor on it to call JSON.stringify() or JSON.parse() as appropriate.

Manually calling $sync() and $apply() can be a safety check. Since storage is across browser tabs there's a potential multithread issue. There is a window of time between the user's change happening and the angular digest calling $sync automatically where a change in data from one browser tab can wipe out a change from the other tab that's attempting to alter the same object at the same time.

But it seems to be one of those only-happens-in-QA-who-is-looking-for-it kinds of issues.

Comment: `$apply()` is called from a `setTimeout` every 100ms.  This is a major performance drag, especially on IE.  I do not recommend using ngStorage for this reason.

Comment: Fun fact: I have run into this exact issue in production code today, and this was the explanation I needed to ensure my stuff sync'd up correctly. Looks like a call to $sync is just what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in [documentation](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

> changes will be automatically sync'd between $scope.$storage, $localStorage, and localStorage - even across different browser tabs!

As it can be seen [here](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/843d78ec719410850d0df136307189a5a3c07f7a/ngStorage.js#L168-L173), explicit $sync call updates $storage to be in sync with local/session storage if it isn't for some reason. Usually it shouldn't be called manually, that's why it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage/blob/master/ngStorage.js

```
 $sync: function () {
                        for (var i = 0, l = webStorage.length, k; i < l; i++) {
                            // #8, #10: `webStorage.key(i)` may be an empty string (or throw an exception in IE9 if `webStorage` is empty)
                            (k = webStorage.key(i)) && storageKeyPrefix === k.slice(0, prefixLength) && ($storage[k.slice(prefixLength)] = deserializer(webStorage.getItem(k)));
                        }
                    }
```

As I understand it writes data from inner `$storage` object to real browser `webStorage` object and used as private function